# Connecting to Analysis Services in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Okay, this may be an insanely stupid question, but how in the world do I connect to Analysis Services in SQL Server 2008?

Basically, I have no idea what to put as my Server Name.

[image]

When I connect to a Database Engine, I'm using mycompname\SQLEXPRESS. If I try to put that as my Server name when connecting to Analysis Services, I get an error saying:

> Cannot connect to mycompname\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2382 (System)

Here's my SQL Server 2008 component information:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 10.0.1600.22
  ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414)
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools - 2007.0100.1600.022
  ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414)
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  - 6.1.7601.17514
  (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
- Microsoft MSXML - 3.0 4.0 6.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer - 9.0.8112.16421
- Microsoft .NET Framework - 2.0.50727.5466
- Operating System - 6.1.7601

Comment: Is the service for Analysis Services running?

Comment: @Lamak - I believe so. SQL Server Configuration Manager says SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Browser are both running. SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) is not running

Comment: Didn't catch that it's SQL Server Express. That version doesn't support Analysis Services

Comment: Two or three things jump out at me here.  First is SQL_PreRelease.  The current version of SQL Server is 2012, which would be an 11.xxx; 10.xxx is 2008 R2.  Therefore, you have a software package that is at least three years out of date. Uninstall this package first.  Second, go to the Microsoft site and download the SQL Server 2008 R2 (or 2012) Express with Advanced Services.  This is the version that includes BI and Reporting.  There is a web loader, or you can copy the entire .MSI to a local folder and install from that.  The latter option allows you to select your own instance name.

Comment: After you install SQL Server, run Microsoft Update.  You might have to do this two or three times, since some SQL patches have patches.  Make sure to start with the SP1 or SP2, and make sure no critical updates remain.  This version of the install will also install a version of Visual Studio, which you use for report development.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there's no Analysis Services for SQLExpress.

According to  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx Analysis Services is included only in Enterprise and Standard edition.

Here's a similar MS page for SQL Server 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.100).aspx

If you did have Analysis Services, then you should be able to connect to it with the same name(s) that you use for the normal data services.  Also, it would show up as a separate explict service in the configuration manager, just like the Agent or the data services.